# SQL database query - return records which have all values from a list (Python)

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, sqlite

I've managed to query and get results for values from a list. But say i have the genres `["Action", "Comedy", "Romance"]` in the list I am using to query. My code below returns all the records which are action, romance and comedy whereas I want it to return only the records that meet all three genres. How can I do this?

The database has a field called genre in which there are multiple genres for each record.

Code:

```
with sqlite3.connect("animeData.db") as  db: #anime database
            c = db.cursor()
            c.execute("select * from t where genre in %s" % repr(self.genreResults).replace('[','(').replace(']',')') ) #self.genreResults is the list containing the genres i want to query
        results = c.fetchall()
        print(results)
        db.commit()
        db.close()
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Database:**

[image]

It's returning all animes which have genres of action and adventure whereas I only want it to return animes which have both. Any suggestions?

Comment: self.genreResults is a list which is populates using user entry but will look like this ['Action', 'genrex'] depending on what the user selected

Comment: For example, if you want to query the records including both Action&Comedy, does this query meet your requirements [select * from t where genre like '%Action%' and genre like '%Comedy%']?

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer. But i cant manually say what genre i want to query in the sql statement as i dont know what the user will select therefore, i have to use a list. How would i execute an sql statement like that for values in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, 'like' clauses meet your requirements but you don't know how to convert list to 'like' clauses.

So the codes will be like below:

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect("animeData.db") as  db: #anime database
    c = db.cursor()
    #self.genreResults is the list containing the genres i want to query
    user_input = self.genreResults  # for example: ['Action','Drama']
    convert_to_like_conditions = ' and '.join(list(map(lambda item : "genre like '%{0}%'".format(item), user_input)))
    print(convert_to_like_conditions) #Output: genre like '%Action%' and genre like '%Drama%'
    c.execute("select * from t where %s" % convert_to_like_conditions ) 
    results = c.fetchall()
    print(results)
    db.commit()
```

You can refer to the documents on [map](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html), [string join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm).

And you probably notice I removed the last line (db.close) of your codes, you can refer to [Understanding Python's "with" statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

Comment: OMG, thanks man ive been searching all over the internet to solve this. Also, thanks for providing the links i understand how you solved now.